# Unable to deal with some critically laid out links

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to parse some information from a webpage. There are few store names along with their links on that webpage. If I click on any of the links, a card like a box pops up containing information. My intention is to click on each link and parse information from that card. However, when I execute my script, it throws an error showing `timeout exception`. I even scrolled down my browser to that position where elements are located to be sure whether it is because of time that it can't click on any link. However, it still throws the same error. How can I get around that? Thanks in advance.

This is the link to that webpage: [Page Link](https://vibekayaks.com/apps/store-locator)

Here is my try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("above_link")

for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#addresses_list li a"))):
    item.click
driver.quit()
```

Elements within which a link resides:

```
<li style="list-style:none; background-image:url(&quot;https://storelocator.w3apps.co/images/orange.png&quot;); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:0px 10px; padding:10px; padding-left:35px; border-bottom:1px dashed #ddd;" onmouseover="hoverStart(601538)" onmouseout="hoverStop(601538)"><a href="#" onclick="focus_and_popup(601538); return false;"><div class="gm_add_name">Adel Outfitters</div>1221 W 4th St <br>Adel Georgia 31620<br><div style="display:none" class="w3-address-country">United States</div>229-896-7105</a><div class="gm_add_distance"></div><a target="_blank" class="directions-link" href="http://maps.google.com/?saddr=+&amp;daddr=1221+W 4th St, Adel, Georgia, 31620">Directions<span class="w3-arrow">➲</span></a></li>
```

The links are located in the left-side area of the map.

Comment: The links are inside an iframe (#store-locator-iframe). Switch inside that iframe first. Also when reading the popup contents you might need to put in some logic to wait for the appropriate one to activate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Grasshopper correctly suggested you need to switch to `iframe` to be able to handle links. Try

```
driver.switch_to.frame("store-locator-iframe")
for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#addresses_list li a"))):
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', item)
    item.click()
    ...

# Switch back if you need to handle elements outside of iframe
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Your suggestion never fails sir. I visualized that the script is successfully clicking each links but i wonder why doesn't any box with information pop up with each click? Any further activity i should perform at this point?

Comment: Sorry sir, i forgot to perform the click event accurately. I think you should change `click` to `click()` in your suggested portion of script. Thankssssss a lot sir.

Comment: A slight little problem I'm facing now. With each click when the box connected to each links pop up, the script is (to me) mistakenly clicking the second link (which is connected to google maps) as well. Can you suggest how should i control my script to click only the first link not the second one which opens up a new window containing google maps. Thanks sir.

Comment: The css selector should be like `"#addresses_list li a:not(.directions-link)"`. It is doing accurately what I was expecting.

Comment: You just need more specific selector. This one `"#addresses_list li a[onclick]"` should work

Comment: Yes, your one doing it the right way as well. One last thing to learn sir: where did you find the `iframe`? Every time i face a serious trouble to find it and identify the right `iframe` among several. Don't get bothered. Thanks again.

Comment: don't use search in dev console. simply check ancestors of required element

Comment: I see. I did the same so many days what you just forbade. Thanks again sir.