# Unable to parse information from a box like container activated upon each click

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to parse some information from a webpage. There are few store names along with their links on that webpage. If I click on any of the links, a card-like box pops up containing information. My intention is to click on each link and parse information from that card. However, when I execute my script, it does click on each link and a box-like container pops up with each click but I can't parse information from it. Looks like i have defined the correct selectors but still no luck.

This is the follow up question of this thread: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186590/unable-to-deal-with-some-critically-laid-out-links)

Link to be used in the below script: [The link](https://vibekayaks.com/apps/store-locator)

This is the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver ; import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("use above link")

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#store-locator-iframe")))

while True:
    try:
        for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#addresses_list li a:not(.directions-link)"))):
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', item)
            item.click()
            time.sleep(4)
    except:
        break

    for elem in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gm-style-iw .gm_popup"))):
        name = elem.find_element_by_class_name("gm_name").text
        phone = elem.find_element_by_class_name("gm_phone").text
        print(name,phone)

driver.quit()
```

Elements within the selector exist:

```
<div class="gm-style-iw" style="top: 9px; position: absolute; left: 15px; width: 353px;"><div style="display: inline-block; overflow: auto; max-height: 529px; max-width: 330px;"><div style="overflow: auto;"><div class="gm_popup"><div class="gm_name">Adel Outfitters</div><div class="gm_address">1221 W 4th St</div><div class="gm_location">Adel, Georgia 31620<div style="display:none" class="w3-address-country">United States</div></div><div class="gm_phone"><span class="gm_phone_label">P:</span> 229-896-7105</div><div class="gm_email">adeloutfitters@yahoo.com<div><div class="gm_website"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/adel-outfitters/132735763434461" target="_blank">https://www.facebook.com/pages/Adel-Outfitters/132735763434461</a></div><br><a target="_blank" class="directions-link" href="http://maps.google.com/?saddr=+&amp;daddr=1221+W 4th St, Adel, Georgia, 31620">Directions<span class="w3-arrow">➲</span></a></div></div></div></div></div><div style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin-top: 9px; padding: 6px; visibility: hidden; font-size: 13px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Roboto, Arial; display: none;"><a href="" target="_blank" style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(66, 127, 237); text-decoration: none;">View on Google Maps</a></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that you should move code that you use to parse each text box in the same loop as link clicking:

```
while True:
    try:
        for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#addresses_list li a:not(.directions-link)"))):
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', item)
            item.click()
            try:
                wait.until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element_by_class_name("gm_name")))
            except:
                pass
            elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gm-style-iw .gm_popup")))
            name = elem.find_element_by_class_name("gm_name").text
            phone = elem.find_element_by_class_name("gm_phone").text
            print(name, phone)
    except:
        break
```

Comment: Right you are sir. It clearly solves the problem. Your intervention always brings productivity. Thanks again.

Comment: Expected to know something unrelated to this thread. You perhaps worked with `splash`. Could you tell me whether it is possible to run `splash` from window without availing docker installation. Just yes or no. Thanks again sir.

Comment: Actually I've never worked with Splash, so I cannot answer